# Typescript Vue addEventListener works with wheel but with scroll doesn't

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, listener

I have a problem that i need to add listener on scrolling in my child component but it doesn't work so. With listening to wheel there is no problem.

```
 mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        window.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll)
        this.handleScroll() // Call it immediately to check for visibility after DOM update
      })
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', this.handleScroll)
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll() {
        console.log('start handleScroll')

        const mainButtons = document.querySelector('.main-buttons')
        if (!mainButtons) return // Return if the main buttons are not rendered yet
        console.log('rendered')
        const rect = mainButtons.getBoundingClientRect()
        const mainButtonsTop = rect.top

        this.showStickyButtons = mainButtonsTop > window.innerHeight
        console.log(mainButtonsTop)
        console.log(window.innerHeight)

        console.log('showStickyButtons:', this.showStickyButtons)
      },
```

I don't have overflow props in both parent and child components. I thought that it could lead to such a problem